# Double arrow elimination

Tags: logic, truth

I know that `P <=> Q` becomes `(p => q) ^ (q => p)`using double arrow elimination but how about the following ?

`~(P <=> Q)` becoming `~(p => q) ^ ~(q => p)` ?

Also

`(~P <=> Q)` becoming `(~p => q) ^ (q => ~p)`?

I want to make sure those are valid steps !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example is incorrect because the negation distributes across the conjunction by way of [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). Therefore, the "AND" symbol needs to become an "OR," but otherwise, it is correct.

Your second example is correct as is.

Comment: Is there another rule to use for example 1 instead of DeMorgan's law? I don't want to get an "OR", its kind of hard to work with them!

Comment: @Questions Nothing comes to mind. Obviously, you could write it as a "NAND" statement, but that's the only thing I can think of and it doesn't seem that useful.

Comment: @Questions Actually, "NOT(P IFF Q)" is logically equivalent to "P XOR Q," but again, I doubt you'll find that useful.

Comment: I am trying to use these in derivations but XOR can not be symbolized, it has to be from the rules.

Comment: I marked your answer since you did answer my question, however if anyone can answer my second question on the comments above, I can at least give +1 for appreciation.

Comment: ~(P <=> Q) is true exactly when P is true and Q is false, or P is false and Q is true. You're not going to get a 'nice' (easy to work with; intuitive) equivalent statement that doesn't use v (OR). But if you do want something equivalent without using it, ((P => Q) => ~(Q => P)) has the right truth-conditions.